# How to check that given email is valid paypal email id or not without using Adaptive API or App ID in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I want to send money to a user's email id which should be a **Valid PayPal Email ID**. So before sending money to user's email id, I want to check that the user has account on PayPal or not.

There is a "GetVerifiedStatus" API to check for valid PayPal id. But this API use App ID and now PayPal is not providing App ID. I am not able to find any correct method to check whether given email id is valid PayPal id or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Connect with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/) to have the receiving user log in with an actual PayPal account before sending money to that email. This is the only way to know a PayPal account exists at that email.

(PayPal allows sending money to email addresses that have no PayPal account associated, and in that eventuality will return the funds in 30 days if not claimed by the owner of that email address. Reminder emails are sent.)